# Saving Oracle query result on database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

What can I do if I need to save each transaction to database with name? I can also call and use transaction with name in SQL developer?

Comment: What do you mean by "transaction" here?  Do you mean "query"?  You could create a view in the database.  You could create a report in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean save the output of your query? to a log file? to the database?